# Matlab - figure draw limit

Tags: image, matlab

I am writing a code that visualizes temperature changes on a drawing and can't overcome a problem that appears. Any help would be really appreciated, I couldn't find anything about it anywhere.

The code is long, but in short:

There is a big 'while' loop in which colored dots and corresponding temperatures are drawn on the 3 figures. The plot moves and shows some statistics, this is for a 24h+ streak of measurements, so ~1500+ points of data. Everything goes smoothly until something, I'm not sure, breaks after about 1000 points of data.

Maybe it's a memory leak, I have no idea as I've never encountered this before. Some lines disappear, all the drawn text data dissapears, the text font changes, plot lines become thicker and circle boundaries become thinner.

Has anyone encountered something similar and knows how to deal with this problem?

[image]

Edit: SOLVED by siliconwafer, switching renderer to zbuffer worked and everything is fine now, thanks :)

Comment: Can you show us some code? What makes you think it's a memory leak?

Comment: Sure, but which part is needed? The 'while' loop? The whole code has like 400 lines. It was first thing that came to my mind, like I said I've never encountered anything like this before.

Comment: What renderer are you using?  It sounds like a potential rendering bug. Perhaps try switching to zbuffer.

Comment: @PawełKowalczyk, posting the 400 lines is probably not useful. Try to reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That would be the first step to debugging this problem anyway.

Comment: Is there an error/warning associated with this display break down ?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't answer before. In fact switching renderer to zbuffer worked brilliantly, thanks a lot - problem solved.